# Emacs: File "..." is not a valid tags file

Tags: emacs, elisp, ctags

When I try to load my TAGS file Emacs keeps saying it is not a valid tags file for some reason. The create command was as simple as it gets:

```
$ ctags -e command-not-found.c
```

It also looks pretty normal:

```
^L
command-not-found.c,246
#define MAXSGST ^?MAXSGST^A6,80
#define MIN(^?MIN^A7,99
char** getdirlst()^?getdirlst^A9,143
void freedirlst(char **dirlst)^?freedirlst^A30,581
int levenshtein(const char *s, const char *t)^?levenshtein^A39,726
int main(int argc, char **argv)^?main^A62,1321
```

The exact error message is: `File /Users/Ron/Documents/Code/command-not-found/TAGS is not a valid tags table`. This was working a few days ago, anyone know what's wrong?
I didn't change my configuration in any way in the past few days.

**EDIT**:
Tried the same thing at work today with existing TAGS files that were working last week, I get the same error.

**EDIT 2**:
It seems I some code I had linked to `find-file-hook` was causing the problems. I wrote a function that determines whether a file is a binary, and if so, opens it in `hexl-mode`. Apparently emacs can't read TAGS files when they're in `hexl-mode`, so it says it isn't valid. A quick fix for this is to determine whether the file is a tags file and leave it alone:

```
;; open binaries in hexl-mode
(defun byte-plaintext-p (byte)
  "Determine whether BYTE is plaintext or not."
  (cl-case byte
    ((?\n ?\r ?\t) t)
    (otherwise (and (<= byte 126) (>= byte 32)))))
(defun file-binary-p (file)
  "Determine whether FILE is a binary file."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents file)
    (cl-loop for c across
             (buffer-substring-no-properties
              1 (min 100 (buffer-size)))
             thereis (not (byte-plaintext-p c)))))
(defun file-tags-naive-p (file) ;; check if first character is '^L'
  "Determine whether FILE is a TAGS file."
  (let ((c (with-temp-buffer
             (insert-file-contents file nil 0 1) (buffer-string))))
    (if (= (aref c 0) 12) t nil)))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (and (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))
                     (> (buffer-size) 0)
                     (not (file-tags-naive-p (buffer-file-name))))
                (if (and (file-binary-p (buffer-file-name))
                         (string= (buffer-local-value 'major-mode
                                                      (current-buffer))
                                  "fundamental-mode"))
                    (hexl-mode)))))
```

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure you can have hyphens in C source file names? Because I'm almost sure that you can't...

Comment: Using command_not_found.c or even commandnotfound.c results in the same error. Not really sure what's going on here...

Comment: You can use `nhexl-mode` (from GNU ELPA) which is similar to `hexl-mode`, except that the buffer is unmodified, only its display appearence is affected.

Answer (score 0):

`/Users/Ron/Documents/Code/command-not-found/command-not-found.c` is indeed not a valid tags table: it's the source file.  The tags table should have name TAGS, so when Emacs asks you for a tags table, don't type "command-not-found.c" but "TAGS" instead.

Comment: No that's just me typing random things on StackOverflow in the middle of the night. I actually tried TAGS as well. I'll edit the question.